# C# code which is always run

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an unity project with multiple scenes.

I switch a lot of time between each scene.

I want to have a C# class which is always run. Is it possible to have a background scene which is always started ?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do exactly here? Is it you want to make a gameobject/script remain constant through out all scene? If that is the case then why dont you use `Dontdestroyonload(gamobject)` ? That will make the gameobject and scripts attached to it remain present in all scene. If not then add more info regarding what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a gameobject, attach your C# script and call `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` this will keep your gameobject, with its scripts, loaded when switching between scenes.

You can check the Unity Docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) for more information on the DontDestroyOnLoad function

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your game you can call a function in you awake() function called SceneManager.LoadScene("YourScene", LoadSceneMode.Additive); This will load the scene you wanted and not destroy your other scenes. If you switch between scenes like this you can make one scene always on working.

See more information [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html);

But if you want only scripts to run on every scene. Use DontDestroyOnLoad function on a gameobject instead. Like @Steffan Venema suggests.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but i both cases do you think Update() method is called ? If the scene is not visible, Update() is even called ?

Comment: Update() should be called on all open scenes.